# mail form made from several text fields

Tags: ios, email, textfield

im very new to app making in xcode, and i have met a small problem problem while making my app.
So what i am trying to do is, i want a page with several text fields, that when you press a button, all the info from the text fields are sent as a mail.
i have everything working, exept one thing. When the mail is sent, all the information is on one line, and i would like the information from each text field, to be on sepperat lines in the mail.
i appriciate any help, and sorry for any spelling mistakes, im from denmark. :)

code:

```
@IBOutlet var text3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text1: UITextField!

    @IBAction func sendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {     let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
    self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property
    let messageBody = text1.text!+text2.text!+text3.text!
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["wastepin@hotmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("New Dumpster")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
    return mailComposerVC
}
func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}
// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

pictures:

[input page (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHkaZ.jpg)

[mail page (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0OQ2.jpg)

Comment: `let messageBody = text1.text!+text2.text!+text3.text!`, you just append them, add an "\n" between them for instance.

Comment: so it should be: text1.text!\n+text2.text!\n+text3.text! or?

Comment: thank you @Larme u are the man! :D

Comment: @peter-boesen : Not sure I deserve those points or not buddy not that I din knew answer but Larme answered it first so this point is rightfully his :) Feel free to accept his answer in case he decide to post the answer buddy :)

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari I just dont know how to give them to him since he put it as a comment instead of an answer, i would have given them to him if i could. :/

Comment: @peter-boesen : Accept his answer if he decides to post it answer :) It will be rewarded to him automatically :)

Comment: @PeterBoesen: It's okay. I won't add an answer since it's already posted. The important thing is that you fixed your issue, better is that you understood why, and that the answer is clearly visible for others developers that may be facing the same issue and see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
let messageBody = text1.text!+"\n"+text2.text!+"\n"+text3.text!
```

Exactly what Larme said :)